# PgSearch pg_search_scope index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, pg-search

Context: I'm using Rails 3 and have a huge users table which usually take like 10 minutes for a search query. So I decided to integrate PgSearch

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Concerns::XmlTagger
    pg_search_scope :qsearch, :against => [:email, :first_name, :last_name]
end
```

But the performance doesn't change. I guess it's all about creating the
right indexes. But I don't see any mention of how to create index for pg_search_scope in their documentation.

Keep in mind that I wanna search agains 3 different columns in a same table, what's the right index, and how to reindex the current data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `include PgSearch` in you `User` model.

Then you can search like

```
User.qsearch("user@example.com, Example, User")
User.qsearch("user@example.com Example User")
```

Got this from the [pg_scope_search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search#pg_search_scope) section.